# How do I put the options that contain a class on the very beginning of options

Tags: javascript

I am making a option that have list of video that has audio and the video that has both audio and video

I have added a class to the videos that have audio and video both and I want them to be at the very beginning of the list

My Current code

```
<select id="download-options" class="select_download">
  <option value="140">mp4 (only audio)</option>
  <option value="137">mp4 - 1080p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="160">mp4 - 144p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="133">mp4 - 240p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="18" class="has_video">mp4 - 360p</option>
  <option value="134">mp4 - 360p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="135">mp4 - 480p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="22" class="has_video">mp4 - 720p</option>
  <option value="136">mp4 - 720p (no audio)</option>
</select>
```

And I want it to be like this

```
<select id="download-options" class="select_download">
  <option value="18" class="has_video">mp4 - 360p</option>
  <option value="22" class="has_video">mp4 - 720p</option>
  <option value="140">mp4 (only audio)</option>
  <option value="137">mp4 - 1080p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="160">mp4 - 144p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="133">mp4 - 240p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="134">mp4 - 360p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="135">mp4 - 480p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="136">mp4 - 720p (no audio)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do your options hard-code or fetch & populated at runtime?

Comment: ya, I'm fetching the options data from somewhere

Comment: @EldernyDev could you show us how you add the options the the select? Because it would be optimal to sort the options before adding them to the select element.

Comment: No, I want to sort after adding them, as I'm adding all options into a var then putting into select element, so basically I want to do this after all options are inside select element

Comment: Alright. But that does mean that you'll have to remove all options and then re-add them again in the correct order. Just so you know.

Comment: Your attempt is wrong. You should sort the options before adding them to the var (hopefully not a var but a const).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the options for the absence of `class`, and if absent, move those to the back:

```js
const list = document.getElementById('download-options');
for (const option of [...list.options]) {
    if (!option.className) list.add(option);
}
list.selectedIndex = 0;
```

```html
<select id="download-options" class="select_download">
  <option value="140">mp4 (only audio)</option>
  <option value="137">mp4 - 1080p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="160">mp4 - 144p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="133">mp4 - 240p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="18" class="has_video">mp4 - 360p</option>
  <option value="134">mp4 - 360p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="135">mp4 - 480p (no audio)</option>
  <option value="22" class="has_video">mp4 - 720p</option>
  <option value="136">mp4 - 720p (no audio)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Even if your solution is pretty cool, I don’t like code that „repairs“ something what was wrong coded before. Using this code the options will be created in wrong order and then sorted, which leads to many not necessary DOM manipulations which are expensive, instead of sorting a list before adding it to the DOM which is much less hungry on performance.

Comment: @Claus, I had upvoted the two comments made about this aspect, but Asker explicitly said *"No, I want to sort after adding them"*. So this answers their question.

Comment: Yes, because I'm fetching the options from somewhere so I would need to wait for all options to be fetched first